# Affected Rows Entity Framework

Tags: ado.net

How do I get the number of rows affected after a SaveChanges()?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) Method returns an int of all items changed.

MSDN Snippet:

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The number of objects in an Added, Modified, or Deleted state when SaveChanges was called.

Comment: Is the details saved anywhere on what was added or deleted. I'm guessing it just something i need to keep track of.

Comment: Take a look at the ObjectContext.ObjectStateManger property.  This should contain data about the state of each entity.